# Is it possible to map routes with path parameters at runtime in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

For context, the application I'm working on receives configuration from an external source, and then spins up a WebApi based on that configuration. For example:

```json
"endpoints": [{
  "connectionId": 0,
  "path": "Books",
  "method": "Get",
  "query": "select * from Books"
  },
  {
    //This is what I am struggling to achieve
    "connectionId": 0,
    "path": "Books/{id}",
    "method": "Get",
    "query": "select top 1 * from Books where Id = {id:guid}"
  },
  {
    "connectionId": 0,
    "path": "Books",
    "method": "Post",
    "query": "insert into Books(Id, Title, Author) values (NEWID(), {title:string}, {author:string})"
  }
];
```

This works fine with simple definitions, but I’ve hit a brick wall trying to figure out if/how path parameters would be possible at runtime. At the moment I’m currently doing something like this to create the endpoints:

```cs
foreach (var endpoint in endpoints)  
{
  var parameters = ParameterParser.Parse(endpoint.Query).ToList();
    
  app.MapPost(  
    endpoint.Path,  
    async (HttpResponse response, [FromBody] JsonElement json) =>  
    {  
        parameters.ForEach(x => x.Value = GetJsonValue(x, json.GetProperty(x.Name)));  
  
        // go and execute the endpoints query and do stuff...
  
        response.StatusCode = 200;  
    });
}
```

But I have no idea if I could build the handler function, which may have any number of parameters, dynamically. I know it's possible to create dynamic methods, but won't the compiler need to know the signature of the handler at compile time, making it impossible to do this in the way that I'm trying to do it? If so, is there an alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#multiple-conventional-routes

Comment: @jdweng Sorry I'm probably just missing something but I'm not sure which part of that you're specifically referring to? That section seems to only be relevant to the `MapControllerRoute` method, but I don't think I can make use of Controllers if I need to dynamically put the whole API together at runtime, which is why I'm using `MapGet`, `MapPost`, etc.

Comment: @Xerillio Sorry, I've added an example of what the configuration might look like and hopefully made things a bit clearer.

Comment: The Route is last part of the URL (path).  So you can use endpoint.Path which is a string to determine what code should process the body data of the request.  Or you can use the deserialized json (body data) to determine what code you should use.  What are you calling "signature of the handler"?  Is it the body data?

Comment: @jdweng What I mean by signature of the handler in this case is basically the parameters of the lambda. For example, depending on the configuration, the handler that I pass to `app.MapGet()` might look like: `async (HttpResponse response, [FromBody] JsonElement json) => ...` with a corresponding path of `/Books`or it could look like something like: `async (string id, HttpResponse response, [FromBody] JsonElement json) =>` with a corresponding path of `Books/{id}`. I want to find a way of generating these dynamically at runtime.

Comment: So if I'm getting this right... given an HTTP method and a URL/path pattern you want to execute a SQL query on a database with some paramenters given via the request URL/body? Seems doable, although, have you thought about the security in this? It seems very difficult if not impossible to prevent malicious queries in the configuration coming from external sources.

Comment: @Xerillio That's correct. I'm not concerned about security at this time, it's an internal dev tool with no access to the outside world.

Comment: I'll delete my first comment to not flood this thread. One last question: have you considered using OData or similar? I'm guessing your goal is to avoid coding repetitive CRUD based endpoints. OData is meant to make some of that much simpler.

Comment: Why do you need a route.  You could have one route and just parse the parameters.

Comment: @jdweng I don't understand what you mean, why wouldn't I need a route? I need an undetermined number of endpoints which are not known until runtime.

Comment: The beginning of the URL is the same for all routes (one endpoint) and the routes are at the end of the URL.  The routes are optional and you can have just one endpoint for all the code.  The use parsed json data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to be able to have a "generic" way to handle all possible Route parameters, in this case you may try something like this:

```
app.MapGet(
    endpoint.Path,
    async (HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) =>
    {
        foreach (var x in parameters) // I don't like ForEach extension method :)
        {
            x.Value = request.RouteValues[x.Name]; // May need to adapt in order to convert to your desired data type
        }

        // go and execute the endpoints query and do stuff...

        response.StatusCode = 200;
    });
```

Comment: I had no idea RouteValues existed but it was exactly what I need, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I will do something like this (I have mapped the json into a class model):

```
foreach (var endpoint in endpointsConf.endpoints) {
    switch (endpoint.method) {
        case "Get":
            app.MapGet(endpoint.path, () => {
                // go and execute the endpoints query and do stuff...
            });
            break;
        case "Post":
            app.MapPost(endpoint.path, (int id) => {
                // go and execute the endpoints query and do stuff...
            });
            break;
    }
}
```

I would probably expand it to handle more than just the ID, but for now, that's what you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got this completly right.

It looks like what you're trying to do is take the information given in the json file that you receieve to configure(or create) methods and then create a Web API from those created methods.

I think it might be an easier approach if you were to go ahead and create a class containing all the methods that a newly created web api may contain and then use the json that you receieve to configure which methods you are going to include in your new Web API.

Within your json you can add what methods the api will contain and add in values to change certain methods

```
For Exmaple:
"endpoints": [{
  "method": "GetByID",
  "id": "5"
},
{
  "method": "GetTopValue"
},
```

Pretty Much just a Web API that has access to a bunch of methods that the web APIs that you are creating may need and then you select which methods you need and slightly edit them if needed from there.

As for the path for the newly created web api, you would have to handle that seperately but I think this may be an easier approach then the way you are currently going about things.

Hope this helps!